# Load Tracking Snippets in Google Tag Manager on click

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So in Germany and I guess in a lot of other countries aswell we have a lot of privacy regulations and they will be tightened in 2018. What is changing is that you have to actively get a users permission to track them instead of an opt out.

So I figured the easiest way to manage that is using the Google Tag Manager. My idea is:

1. User comes on a website and gets a prompt where he can agree or
   disagree with beeing tracked.
2. If he agrees a cookie is set and the tracking snippets are loaded.
3. If he reload the page the GTM would check if the cookie is set and if
   so load the snippets.

I have two questions tho. My first question is if the tracking snippets will work even if they are loaded after the cookie check. For example Google Analytics and Facebook.

My second question is: What is the best way to load the snippets in step 2? Do I have to configure a trigger in GTM if the button on the website was clicked?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve that, is like that:

*I presume that if he agrees, your website is setting cookie `acceptTracking` and then **reloading the page***

In **all your website pages** wrap GTM code into condition if cookie exists

```
if (document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*acceptTracking=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?                     
   id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
}
```

That means if cookie doesn't exist, you don't need to load GTM at all.

*Because even if you will include GTM without any tags, it will still track user clicks. That's way I think better way is do not load GTM at all*